# How to select two columns having different conditions for each colums from MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

For example lets consider a table like:

[image]

lets say i want to select two columns. Column one should contain all the names before 2019-09-11 and column two should contain all the names after 2019-09-11. So basically there would be two different where conditions for the two columns.

expected output would be:

[image]

MySQL version is **5.6.34-log**

IS there anyway to do so?

Comment: What does your expected output looks like ? What is your MySQL version ? How do you define the order of the expected output ? (Note that data is *unordered*, so without explicit ordering definition, the results will be *non-deterministic*)

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ? Run `SELECT Version();` on your MySQL client (PHPMyadmin, workbench etc) and report the result of the same.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I have attached the expected output and my MySQL version is 5.6.34-log

Comment: Also, look back at your expected output, the ordering is inconsistent. Do you have a primary key in the table ?

Comment: What do you plan to do with this result set? Display it as-is on a report?

Answer (score 3):

> lets say i want to select two columns. Column one should contain all
>   the names before 2019-09-11 and column two should contain all the
>   names after 2019-09-11. So basically there would be two different
>   where conditions for the two columns.

Little bit wierd request for a RDMS. 
Anyhow the query below is not tested but i would use two sub queries (derived tables ) with a MySQL user variable to generate a row_number which you can use to join later..

**note**
As SQL is orderless i am assuming here you don't care about a sort in the columns.

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    *
    , (@row_num1 := @row_num1 + 1) AS row_number    
  FROM  
   t  
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num1 := 0) AS init_user_param                  
  WHERE 
   `timestamp` < '2019-09-11'  
) AS left_column
LEFT/RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    *
    , (@row_num2 := @row_num2 + 1) AS row_number
  FROM  
   t
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num2 := 0) AS init_user_param                  
  WHERE 
   `timestamp` > '2019-09-11'  
) AS right_column
ON
 left_column.row_number = right_column.row_number
```

> **Comment of Madhur Bhaiya** 
>   This will require a FULL JOIN; because we dont know which side has more rows.

Very true you would need to use LEFT JOIN if the left column contains more records. And RIGHT JOIN when the right column contains more records.

As this is a wierd request anyway i would suggest using programming language or MySQL's `PREPARE/EXECUTE` to build the query dynamic so 
FULL JOIN emulation is not required..

**Warning using EXECUTE/PREPARE in MySQL to generate dynamic SQL is complex if you never seen or usaged it before...**

**Query**

```
SET @sql = CONCAT("
SELECT 
 *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    *
    , (@row_num1 := @row_num1 + 1) AS row_number
  FROM  
   t  
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num1 := 0) AS init_user_param                  
  WHERE 
   `timestamp` < '2019-09-11'  
) AS left_column
",

(
  SELECT 
   CASE
    WHEN left_column_count > right_column_count
    THEN 'LEFT JOIN'
    ELSE 'RIGHT JOIN' 
   END
  FROM (
    SELECT
         SUM(`timestamp` < '2019-09-11') AS left_column_count
       , SUM(`timestamp` > '2019-09-11') AS right_column_count
    FROM 
     t
  ) AS t
)                 

," (
  SELECT 
    *
    , (@row_num2 := @row_num2 + 1) AS row_number
  FROM  
   t
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num2 := 0) AS init_user_param                  
  WHERE 
   `timestamp` > '2019-09-11'  
) AS right_column
ON
 left_column.row_number = right_column.row_number
");


SELECT @sql; 
PREPARE s FROM @sql;
EXECUTE s;
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/GryAZjEVng6GHxUvCDaci/3)

Comment: This will require a `FULL JOIN`; because we dont know which side has more rows. Also, without order by data will be non-deterministic (but considering OP himself is unclear about ordering, so that can be passed off).

Comment: *"This will require a FULL JOIN; because we dont know which side has more rows."* Ideally yes @MadhurBhaiya MySQL's `EXEXUTE/PREPARE` to the rescue as `FULL JOIN` emulation was tested to a bit to iffy wierd for this case..  *"Also, without order by data will be non-deterministic (but considering OP himself is unclear about ordering, so that can be passed off)"* i know ANSI/ISO SQL standards ordering "defaults" to be non-deterministic or better said platform depended...